# How can I enable multiple segments of a UISegmentedControl to be selected?

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

Lets say my UISegmentedControl has 8 numbered segments. I would like for the user to be able to turn on 2, 3, or more of them at once. Toggling them. Essentially like a bits in a byte. Is this possible? I believe it is on regular Mac OS X but I can't seem to find a way to do it in the iPhone SDK.

If I have to simulate this by putting buttons into a view, is there any way to do the following:

1. Round the corners of the view so that it looks like the "bar" style UISegmentedControl?
2. Use the built-in backgrounds the "bar" style has on the buttons?
3. Give the buttons a shadow like the whole "bar" style has? (not the text)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't possible using UIKit.  I would recommend creating a custom control, or an array of `UISwitch` controls, representing each of the options in your UISegmentedControl.

Answer (score 9):

Update: The custom control I mentioned here no longer works under iOS 13.

This is the best custom control I've found that allows multiple segments to be selected concurrently:

https://github.com/yonat/MultiSelectSegmentedControl

This one is a subclass of UISegmentedControl, which is convenient. I've forked it here:

https://github.com/stewartmacdonald/MultiSelectSegmentedControl

and added some code examples to the ReadMe and added a method that allows you to get an NSArray of the titles of all selected segments.

Comment: `MultiSelectSegmentedControl` is very nice. It extends `UISegmentedControl` so all its methods are available.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is to create your own segmentedcontrol with UIButton.

Marco

Comment: One way to do this, which I have done in shipping apps, is to use a UILabel with rounded edges and put rectangular UIButtons inside. This way you can get the rounded edges for the combined control. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a way to do this in XCode now. In the Attributes Inspector, there is a section with Segment, Title, Image, Behavior. The behavior options are "Enabled" and "Selected". You can selecte "Selected" for multiple segments.

Comment: I don't think this works. In Xcode when I select "Selected" for a segment, the other segments all become unselected. Further the methods for UISegmentedControl include setEnabled:forSegmentAtIndex but not setSelected:forSegmentAtIndex (which would be handy). I'm trying to do the same as the OP and it appears I need to create a custom control. Kind of ironic since the helper buttons at the top Xcode itself are exactly what I'm shooting for (Mac app though).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try https://github.com/tayhalla/THSegmentedControl
it is an actual subclass of `UISegmentedControl` so it fits nicely with Interface builder and everything.

Comment: It is a subclass of `UIControl` not `UISegmentedControl `