# Multiple selection of segments in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

Can the UISegmentedControl allow multiple selection of segments?
Otherwise should we create custom controls?

Comment: possible duplicated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029570/how-can-i-enable-multiple-segments-of-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-be-selected

Comment: You can custom with buttons.

Comment: If [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39714308/5501940) resolved your issue, please don't forget to accept it (green tick it) :) FYI, accepting an answer leads to: - gives the answerer +15 reputation points. - gives you (asker) +2 reputation points. - And the most important thing, it gives an indication for the viewers that this answer is the appropriate solution for this issue.

Answer (score 6):

By default, [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol) does *not* support multiple selection.

For such a case, a custom control should be the desired solution; I would recommend to check [ATHMultiSelectionSegmentedControl](https://github.com/attheodo/ATHMultiSelectionSegmentedControl) library, it does provided the desired behavior of what are you looking for, it is easy to use and now it is compatible with the latest Swift version (which is 3 at the time I posted my answer).