# how to do multiple selection in segmented control in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

it looks like `UISegmentedControl` doesn't allow user to do multiple selection by default.

I have seen some github libraries for obj-c, how allow multiple segment selection using swift?

[image]

how to do multiple selection in segmented control in swift ?

Comment: You don't need a new library written in Swift. Any existing library written in Objective-C can be linked against your project, and all of its functionality is accessible from within Swift — no Objective-C need be written by you. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift) for an example.

Comment: You could try implementing a collection view with three cells and multiple selection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple selection of segments in UISegmentedControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215378/multiple-selection-of-segments-in-uisegmentedcontrol)

Answer (score 1):

`UIKit` does not provide any feature to support for multiple selections in `UISegmentControl`. Recommendation would be to create a custom control, better to use an array of `UISwitch` controls where it represents each of the options in your `UISegmentControl`.